# Why adding a row with another row in square matrix A doesn't change the $\det(A)$ value?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Why adding a row with another multiplied row in square matrix $A$ doesn't change the $\det(A)$ value?

Comment: Do you know that the determinant is a multilinear function of the rows of a matrix? And that interchanging two rows changes the sign of the determinant?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598219/effect-of-elementary-row-operations-on-determinant, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211013/why-is-the-determinant-invariant-under-row-and-column-operations/

Answer (score 1):

Because of:

1. the linearity of the determinant according to the lines
2. the anti-symmetry of the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

To develop the answer of @mookid note that:
multilinearity means that that the detrminat is a linear function of his (vector) rows $\mathbf{a}_h$, so you have:
$$
\det (\mathbf{a}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{a}_i+k\mathbf{a}_{j},\cdots, \mathbf{a}_{j},\cdots \mathbf{a}_n)^T=\det(\mathbf{a}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{a}_i,\cdots \mathbf{a}_{j},\cdots \mathbf{a}_n)^T +k\det(\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_{j},\cdots \mathbf{a}_{j},\cdots \mathbf{a}_n)^T
$$
Now, the determinat is also antisymmetric and this means that if two rows are the same the determinat is null, so: $\det(\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_{j},\cdots \mathbf{a}_{j},\cdots \mathbf{a}_n)^T=0$.